# How to make input box big as text area in html

Tags: html, css

I have to show the a new quote in the input box.  The input box is too small.

```html
<form action="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" method="get" id=usrform>
  <div id="input">
    <label for=quote>New Quote will appear</label><br>
    <input name="text" id="quote" type="text" value="" multiple="multiple">
  </div>
  <button id=getquotebtn type=button>Get A New Quote</button>
  <button id=twitterbtn type=submit>tweet</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged "javascript" and not "html"? If you want something the size of a textarea, why don't you just use a textarea? Anyway, you can change the size of the input by setting the `size` attribute or by using CSS. `multiple="multiple"` makes no sense for a `type="text"` input - if you're trying to make a multi-line input, well, that's what a textarea is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" method="get" id=usrform>
  <div id="input">
    <label for=quote>New Quote will appear</label><br>
    <textarea name="text" id="quote" type="text" value=""  cols="5" rows="5">your quote is here</textarea>
  </div>
  <button id=getquotebtn type=button>Get A New Quote</button>
  <button  id=twitterbtn type=submit>tweet</button>
</form>
```

Please use textarea instead of the input type text. This is the good practice

Answer (score 0):

For an input that allows a person to type multiple lines, use `<textarea>`. You can also define the cols and rows the textarea can have, basically creating new lines at that point

Answer (score -1):

Option 1:

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
   $("#getquotebtn").click(function(){
        setInput("hello world ") //
   })
})

function setInput(val){
    //alert()
   $("#quote").val(val)
   $("#quote").css("width", (val.length * 6) +"px"); //dynamically set the width length of input element
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" method="get" id=usrform>
      <div id="input">
        <label for=quote>New Quote will appear</label><br>
        <input name="text" id="quote" type="text" value="" multiple="multiple">
      </div>
      <button id=getquotebtn type=button>Get A New Quote</button>
      <button  id=twitterbtn type=submit>tweet</button>
    </form>
```

Option 2:

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
   $("#getquotebtn").click(function(){
     setInput("hello world")
   })
})

function setInput(val){
  $ ("#quote").val(val)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" method="get" id=usrform>
          <div id="input">
            <label for=quote>New Quote will appear</label><br>
            <textarea name="text" id="quote" type="text" value="" multiple="multiple"> </textarea>
          </div>
          <button id=getquotebtn type=button>Get A New Quote</button>
          <button  id=twitterbtn type=submit>tweet</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: let me know if you have any concern